# Why does my col-x doesn't work as expected in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a `Login` button to my navbar in bootstrap, but when I add col-x to separate them equally, but they just cover 50% of the width of the navbar and nothing more. But when I use col-x outside then navbar it works perfectly.

The code

```
 <!-- Navigation -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-blue sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <h1 class="display-3">Petitions</h1>
          </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                Get Started
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4"> 
            <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarResponsive"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Начало</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Цел на компанията</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">За компанията</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
 <!-- Navigation -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you want to make something like this:

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md sticky-top" style="background-color: #000000;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
      <div class="col-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <h1 class="display-3">Petitions</h1>
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            Get Started
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4"> 
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Начало</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Цел на компанията</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">За компанията</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```